# Getting the list of polymer published properties

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

Is there a way of getting the list of all [published properties](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#published-properties) defined in a polymer component? (e.g. get the available properties of component public API)

```
<polymer-element name="sample-component"
                 attributes="foo1 foo2" bar="10">
   /* ... */
</polymer-element>

<sample-component foo1="5"></sample-component>


document.querySellector('sample-component').attributes;
// returns bar and foo1 (which have a value assigned to them)
// but I want to get foo1 and foo2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to use `element.publish` to get the list of published properties for an element. (In polymer 1.0 `element.properties` does the same).

`element.getAttribute('attributes)` won't include the publish properties that are setup in a [`publish` block](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#published-properties).

Comment: What about polymer 1.0? published doesn't seem to work in polymer 1.0 Thanks

Comment: Did you try `element.properties`?

Comment: That was it. It was my first guess but by some reason it didn't work first time I tried it. Edited answer to include polymer 1.0. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access the element definition (i.e. the `polymer-element` itself) through the `element` property. So

```
document.querySelector('sample-component')
  .element.getAttribute('attributes')
```

gives you `'foo1 foo2'` (btw. inside an element you can simply write `this.element`.)

Be aware that this only works after Polymer has registered and processed all elements, so depending on where you want to use this statement, you may have to put it into a `polymer-ready` event handler:

```
<script>
  addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    console.log(document.querySelector('sample-component')
      .element.getAttribute('attributes'));
  });
</script>
```

**Update:**

If you want to get a list of all published properties (i.e. the ones in the `attributes` attribute plus the ones of the `publish: {}` property), you can use

```
   Object.keys(document.querySelector('sample-component').publish)
```

which gives you `['foo1', 'foo2']`.

Comment: Thanks @dirk-grappendorf. Sorry I wasn't using the accurate terminology in my question. I edited the question with the link to Polymer docs.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. But Eric was faster ;-)

Comment: FYI calling the publish property now gives you an object with key value pairs versus the array listed in the question.