# Attribute key value object

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm looking for a way to determine what attributes a polymer element has without interacting with the attributes directly. I stumbled upon `this.attributes` accidentally and it does contain all the information that I need It's just not very pretty. I was wondering if there was a simple attributes object that existed already. Something simple like this.

```
{
  "src": "http://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg",
  "alt": "stackoverflow"
}
```

Here's how you'd convert it using underscore, it's a little ugly.

```
this.attr_obj = _.extend.apply(null, _.map(this.attributes, function(attribute){
  var temp = {};
  temp[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
  return temp;
}));
```

Comment: [].map.call(this.attributes, function(attribute){ this[attribute.name] = attribute.value; return this;},{})[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the [answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187164/340688).

> It's best to use `element.publish` to get the list of published properties for an element. (In polymer 1.0 `element.properties` does the same).
>
> `element.getAttribute('attributes)` won't include the publish properties that are setup in a [`publish` block](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#published-properties).